# Как сделать два RecyclerLayout на одном активити?

Tags: android

я описываю их так

```
private void initRecyclerViewListGet() {
    recyclerViewGet = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.robobet_list_get_cv);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerViewGet.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewGet.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RobobetListGetAdapter adapter = new RobobetListGetAdapter(initRvListGet());
    recyclerViewGet.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Второй также только в менеджере меняю VERTICAL. Они у меня в разных LinearLayout-ах. Проблема в описании layoutManager?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#005c89">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/robobet_rv_l"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_robo_l"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="#005c89"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/robobet_list_rv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/robobet_rv_r"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_robo_r"
        android:background="#005c89"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"    />

</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/robobet_rv_get"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/rv_list"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#c7d6e9"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/robobet_txt_match"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="@string/robobet_txt_match"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/robobet_txt_forecatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/robobet_txt_forecatch"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/robobet_txt_kf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/robobet_txt_kf"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/robobet_txt_rate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/robobet_txt_rate"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/robobet_txt_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="@string/robobet_txt_score"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/robobet_list_get_cv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_robobet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    />
```

А вот сам XML в котором они находятся

Также сделал скрин, слева, как должно быть, справа с пропавшим списком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: они должны одновременно отображаться или один вместо другого в зависимости от условий?

Comment: Собственно проблема в вопросе не описана. У вас что-то падает или не отображается или отображается не так как надо?

Comment: может тогда лучше воспользоваться expandable list или  expandable recycler?

Comment: покажите XML разметку

Comment: @ЮрийСПб есть список видов спорта(горизонтальный), а есть список который выходит из выбранного вида спорта(вертикальный) и находится чуть ниже

Comment: @metalurgus добавил у сам вопрос разметку

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, всё ещё не ясна проблема. У вас что-то не отображается?

Comment: попробуйте для начала у всех элементов с `layout_weight` выставить `android:layout_height`  0dp

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, второй RecyclerView -- robobet_list_get_cv"

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, пустое место вместо списка или на экран не влезло? Всем будет лучше, если вы будете подробнее описывать проблему сразу. Ну и скриншот не помешает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил, извините что так по частям... но мне кажется что проблема в самом layoutManager, что я не правильно задаю параметры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто не дали вашему RecyclerView места

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/robobet_rv_get"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/rv_list"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#c7d6e9"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <!-- Тут у вас заголовки и они заняли всю высоту контейнера.-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/robobet_list_get_cv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

У вас поместились заголовки только, т.к. высота их контейнера - `match_parent`

А высота родительского контейнера - 50dp и для RecyclerView места по высоте не осталось.

Вам надо для обоих LinearLayout в приведённом в ответе фрагменте разметки задать высоту `wrap_content`

Comment: как всегда спасибо!

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, пожалуйста) Кстати, ваша репутация теперь позволяет вам не только принимать ответы, но и голосовать за них)